# How to Import and extract elements from a list of arrays saved as a text file in python

Tags: python, arrays, import

I have a .txt file, which is a list of arrays. I want to import that file and extract elements of that list of arrays and work with them.
when I use

```
with open('filename.txt') as f:
        list1 = eval(f.read())
```

which works well when I want to import a list of numbers, does not work when the elements are arrays. It gives

```
NameError: name 'array' is not defined
```

Problem is perhaps with the eval() function not working well with arrays? Could you help me import this list of arrays?

Comment: Please provide a sample of the file contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file content is, for example:

```
array([1,2,3])
```

...then...

```
from numpy import array

with open('filename.txt') as f:
    a = eval(f.read())
    print(a)
    print(type(a))
```

...will produce...

```
[1 2 3]
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```